# Ambiguity in instruction flow in Pic assembly

Tags: assembly, pic

In this code, I am checking if button is pressed, if SW11 is pressed, I am forwarding the flow to **compare** function.The structure of keys is following:

[image: Picture]

```
 aftersw00:



    movf    counter,0
    call    ledtable
    movwf   countertab
    call    led

    call    disp1

    movf    display2,0
    call    displaytable23
    movwf   displaytab2
    call    disp2                  //show on display2


    movf    display3,0
    call    displaytable23
    movwf   displaytab3
    call    disp3                 //show on display3
    call    assignRandomNumber
    call    delay

    bsf     PORTB,1               //here I make RB1,to disable sw4,sw5,sw6,sw7
    btfsc   PORTB,7               //here I check if RB7 pressed, if pressed RB7 becomes 0 
        goto    $+5           //if not pressed, it must go +5 instructions forward
        btfss   PORTB,4        //check if button is released
    goto    $-1                  
        bcf     PORTB,1        //if pressed and released, goto compare function
        goto    compare
    bcf     PORTB,1

    btfsc   PORTB,4             //check for sw4 press, it RB4 initially 1,when pressed it becomes 5
        goto    $+5             //if not pressed go +5 instructions forward
        btfss   PORTB,4         //to check if released
    goto $-1
        decf    display2,1      //if pressed and released, decrement display2                            
    goto    aftersw00           //and go to aftersw00 function again
    btfsc   PORTB,5               
        goto    $+5
        btfss   PORTB,5
    goto $-1
        incf    display2,1
    goto    aftersw00               
    btfsc   PORTB,6
        goto    $+5
        btfss   PORTB,6
    goto $-1
        decf    display3,1
    goto    aftersw00
    btfsc   PORTB,7
        goto    aftersw00
    btfss   PORTB,7
    goto    $-1
        incf    display3,1
    goto    aftersw00
```

---

```
 compare:                     basic function to display what is now display

    movf    counter,0
    call    ledtable
    movwf   countertab
    call    led

    call    disp1

    movf    display2,0
    call    displaytable23
    movwf   displaytab2
    call    disp2



    movf    display3,0
    call    displaytable23
    movwf   displaytab3
    call    disp3
    goto    compare
```

I make RB1 disable by setting

```
 bsf PORTB,1
```

to make sure that third line, that is SW11 is pressed, but from now I increment the **display2** and **display3** variables only up to 2 and then displays showing something unpredictable

UPDATE:I want to understand why instruction flow differs, why display2 and display3 can be incremented only up to 2

Answer (score 0):

On first look...
The reason why `incf    display3,1` isn't executed is that you have at first pin checking:

```
btfsc   PORTB,7       //here I check if RB7 pressed, if pressed RB7 becomes 0 
goto    $+5           //if not pressed, it must go +5 instructions forward
btfss   PORTB,4       //check if button is released
```

instead...

```
btfsc   PORTB,4       //here I check if RB4 pressed, if pressed RB4 becomes 0 
goto    $+5           //if not pressed, it must go +5 instructions forward
btfss   PORTB,4       //check if button is released
```

So if `PORTB,7` is clear (pressed) the rest of code should never executed.

By the way.
When you press one of buttons the MCPU wiat in loop until the button is relased. This is bad  code design!